# Is there any way I can send custom fields to mongo repository to search on?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want a way to send custom fields to spring repository and query should fetch data on basis of that field and fetch the result.

```
{
    "_id" : "fa744095-d789-4bfd-b7be-65677ce00c59",
    "data" : {
        "Single select RD" :     "B@%sl%@X",
        "Multiple select RD" : [ 
            "A@%sl%@E", 
            "B@%sl%@X", 
            "B@%sl%@Y"
        ],
        "Single Domain data" : [ 
            {
                "Header-2" : "value",
                "Esa" : "value",
                "Title" : "title1"
            }
        ],
        "Multiple Domain data" : [ 
            {
                "Header-2" : "value",
                "Esa" : "value",
                "Title" : "title1"
            }, 
            {
                "Header-2" : "value",
                "Esa" : "value",
                "Title" : "title2"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

So this is my mongo document. Data type for 'data' field is Object. Now I want to fetch fields on the basis of "Single select RD" field. I can achieve it using @Query annotation in MongoRepository but this "Single select RD" field can be anything. So is there a way I can pass this value to @Query annotation or can do it using jpa?

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass method parameters to the query using named parameters, define these using the @Param annotation inside our repository method declaration.

```
@Query("SELECT d FROM Data d WHERE d.Single select RD= :status")
Data findDataByStatus(@Param("status") String status);
```